# When to use "вовсе не" and when to use "нисколько не"?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> Дарование **вовсе не** обязательно.
>
> Я **нисколько не** сомневаюсь в том, ...

I assume they both essentially mean "not at all", emphasising negation, but I'm not sure how they differ in meaning and usage.

Is the former often coupled with an adjective/adverb and the latter with a verb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess they can be thought of in terms of the following distinction

**вовсе не  = совсем не = отнюдь не<sup>*very high register*</sup>** - `not at all`

**нисколько<sup>*conjoined*</sup> не = ничуть не = ни капли/грамма не<sup>*colloquial*</sup>** - `not in the slightest`, `not a/the least bit`

Comment: Hi. How does "далеко не" compare?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens it's only applied to adjectives and adverbs in the context of comparison with the addition of так and как (далеко не так умён, как ...), and to nouns by itself (я далеко не знаток японского)

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens or with the combination "такой..., как/какой/каким..."

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens English equivalents are ***by far not as ... as ...*** and ***far from being a(n) ....***

Answer (score 2):

**Нисколько не** is used as a slight exaggeration mostly with verbs and predicatives (in impersonal sentences ) like нисколько не жалко, нисколько не больно, мне нисколько не хочется. It isn't used with adjectives though or nouns. The meaning is "absolutely "not in any amount"( ни в коей мере).

> Я нисколько в этом не сомневаюсь – Я совершенно в этом не сомневаюсь
>   Он нисколько не жалел о содеянном – Он совсем не жалел о содеянном
>   Он нисколько не сомневался в сказанном – Он абсолютно не сомневался в сказанном

**Вовсе не** is highly colloquial, used more often to express a firm negation, when a person is confident.(уверенное отрицание). The usage is more universal, it can be followed by a verb, a predicative, an adverb, an adjective, a noun.

> Я вовсе не собирался вас обижать. Он вовсе не бедный человек. Мне вовсе не жалко.

Answer (score 1):

**Вовсе не** is about plain denying a *fact*: **not at all** or '**absolutely not**':

> You *absolutely don't* have to be gifted.

**Нисколько** is literally about *quantity* and means '**no amount** (of doubt)'. **Нисколько не** in combination with a verb means '**to no extent**', so here are possible translations:

> To *no extent* I doubt, that...
>
> I have *not the least* doubt, that...